# Workaround to ICS "locking surface"-error

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-activity

The error is basically described [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22406). If an activity is finished to quickly after it is created, the UI is locked with an exception: `"IllegalArgumentException locking surface"` This is a huge problem and I'm looking for the cleanest possible workaround.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible I use a `Runnable` instead of an `Activity`.  However, it is messy to move data in and out of a `Runnable`.  It's a stable workaround, but not clean.

This issue is only seen with short duration `Activity` instances on the `Galaxy Nexus`.  It does not happen on older Android phones.